# Table Update Event Handler

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am investigating the capabilities of the new delegate & event subscription pattern in AX 2012.

At the moment I am looking to detect when a particular field has been modified, for example when `SalesTable.SalesStatus` is changed to `SalesStatus::Invoiced`.

I have created the following post-event handler and attatched to the SalesTable.Update method;

```
public static void SalesTable_UpdatePosteventHandler(XppPrePostArgs _args)
{
    Info("Sales Update Event Handler");
}
```

Now I know I can get the `SalesTable` from the `_args`, but **how can I detect a field has changed?** I could really use a before & after version, which makes me think I am subscribing to the wrong event here.

Comment: Probably not your answer but can you detect changes using the salesTable.orig() values?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.orig.aspx

Comment: @ian_scho I dont think it works because I am looking after the update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `update` method does not update the field, you can use a `pre` [event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg839762.aspx) on the update method. If you want to monitor the `PriceGroup` field on the `CustTable` table then create a class called `CustTableEventHandler` containing this method:

```
public static void preUpdateHandler(XppPrePostArgs _args)
{
    CustTable custTable = _args.getThis();
    if (custTable.PriceGroup != custTable.orig().PriceGroup)
        info(strFmt("Change price group from '%1' to '%2'", custTable.orig().PriceGroup, custTable.PriceGroup));
}
```

A `post` event handler will not work, as `orig()` will return the changed record.
Also if the the record is updated using `doUpdate` your handler is not called.

You could also override the `aosValidateUpdate` on `CustTable`, which is called even if `doUpdate` is used. This method is always run on the AOS server.

```
public boolean aosValidateUpdate()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    if (this.PriceGroup != this.orig().PriceGroup)
        info(strFmt("Change price group from '%1' to '%2'", this.orig().PriceGroup, this.PriceGroup));
    return ret;
}
```

Yet another option would be a global change to the `Application.eventUpdate` method.
From the header of the method:

> Serves as a callback that is called by the kernel when a record in a
>   table is updated, provided that the kernel has been set up to monitor
>   records in that table.
>
> A developer can set up the kernel to call back on updates for a given
>   table by inserting a record into the DatabaseLog kernel table with all
>   fields set to relevant values, which includes the field logType set to
>   EventUpdate. It is possible to set up that the kernel should call back
>   whenever a record is updated or when a specific field is updated.This
>   is very similar to how logUpdate is called and set up. The call
>   of this method will be in the transaction in which the record is
>   updated.

This method is used by the [alert rule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa498338.aspx) notification system. I would recommend against this, unless it is a global change (like alert rules).

Alert rules can be extended [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa673670.aspx).

Comment: nice answer Jan I will get back to you when I have tried a few of these out

Comment: Jan, you pointed me in the right direction. You may wish to add this to the last art of your answer as I am using is extensively http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa673670.aspx - also, I will leave the bounty open until it expires just in case!